# Get Ref Cursor from dbms_sql.open_cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have been asked to try to fix some existing PL/SQL code at work and I am new to PL/SQL. I am sorry if this is a stupid question.

Is there a way to take the cursor id returned by dbms_sql.open_cursor and get a REF CURSOR? Something like this:

```
procedure DoSomething (po_cursor out REF CURSOR) is

    lv_cursorid integer;

begin

    lv_cursorid := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;

    po_cursor := get_cursor_by_id(lv_cursorid);

end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the docs, `dbms_sql.to_refcursor(lv_cursorid)` should do it